# Como percorrer um repositório Git?

Tags: git

Quero testar algumas métricas de software e preciso percorrer um repositório git, mas preciso fazer isso utilizando os próprios comandos git, por exemplo, git log, git show...

Uma das métricas que quero saber é o número de linhas que tem em um projeto desconsiderando comentários, imports e etc. Para isso, preciso percorrer todas as classes do projeto.

Comment: Conforme [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822471/1452488), você consegue com `git ls-files | xargs cat | wc -l`, que é uma solução baseada nas ferramentas externas. Apenas com Git acho que não será possível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procure por softwares prontos que já vão te dar essas métricas:

- Sonarqube [Test Metrics](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/)
- qTest Insights [Test metrics](https://www.qasymphony.com/software-testing-tools/qtest-insights/test-metrics/)

Outro ponto:

Procure por métricas que são utilizadas no dia de hoje:

- Cycle time: [How to Calculate Cycle Time](https://leankit.com/blog/2016/12/kanban-calculations-cycle-time/)
- Code churn: [A magical metric for software quality](https://dzone.com/articles/code-churn-a-magical-metric-for-software-quality)

Métricas como número de linhas, quantidade de commits, não são boas métricas, não vão te dizer muito sobre o código.

Comment: A ideia seria desenvolver um software de métricas, então não faz sentido procurar por software de métricas.

Comment: Seria interessante deixar a sua pergunta mais clara, edite-a e inclua essa informação, pois muda o cenário.
De qualquer maneira parte da resposta contém alguma métricas que podem te ajudar. E continua valendo o que eu disse na resposta, contar linhas não é uma boa métrica.